# Name for altering a well known phrase in an obvious to convey a "new" concept?

Tags: analogy

I think most people are well aware what a drag-queen is (a man dressed/acting as a woman), but I've never before today heard the phrase "drag-king"

I can however, easily arrive at the conclusion that the speaker intends to convey the concept of "a woman dressed/acting as a man"

-

Back in the 70s, Richard Nixon's actions gave us "watergate" - simply the name of a group of buildings. There's no real reason why the -gate prefix should become synonymous with something scandalous, but it has and someone can say to me "iPhone 6 - bendgate!" and I arrive at the understanding that there's a scandal relating to the phone bending

-

Is there a name for the process that one goes through, taking the well known, modifying it in an obvious way so that the listener can receive the new info/modification, trace enough of the original phrase to understand what it was and apply the transformation in their own mind?

Comment: FF's idiom-warping.

Comment: It's a type of metaphor and metanym, I think.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn’t use it in quite the same way as what you want, but in his *The Devil’s Dictionary* Ambrose Bierce coined a phrase that may serve, which I have **emphasized** in this quote:

> **SAW**, *n*: A trite popular saying, or proverb. (Figurative and colloquial.) So called because it makes its way into a wooden head.
>   Following are examples of **old saws fitted with new teeth**.
>
> > A penny saved is a penny to squander.
> >     A man is known by the company that he organizes.
> >     A bad workman quarrels with the man who calls him that.
> >     A bird in the hand is worth what it will bring.
> >     Better late than before anybody has invited you.
> >     Example is better than following it.
> >     Half a loaf is better than a whole one if there is much else.
> >     Think twice before you speak to a friend in need.
> >     What is worth doing is worth the trouble of asking somebody to do it.
> >     Least said is soonest disavowed.
> >     He laughs best who laughs least.
> >     Speak of the Devil and he will hear about it.
> >     Of two evils choose to be the least.
> >     Strike while your employer has a big contract.
> >     Where there’s a will there’s a won’t.

Answer (score 1):

The word "***snowclone***" was coined to describe precisely this kind of templatized-cliche, first promulgated by [LanguageLog](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000350.html):

> At last a suitable name has been proposed for the some-assembly-required adaptable cliché frames. I mean formulae like these (where the **N**, **X**, **Y**, **Z** are filled in to taste):
>
> *If Eskimos have **N** words for snow, **X** surely have **Y** words for **Z**.*
>
> *In space, no one can hear you **X**.*
>
> ***X*** is the new **Y**.